# Create a folder on desktop via Vbscript

Tags: vbscript, directory, desktop

I have 2 scripts but could not combine them

Create a folder script

```
Option Explicit
Dim objNetwork, objComputer
Dim objFSO, objFSOText, objFolder, objFile
Dim strDirectory, strFile, MakeObject

strDirectory = "Folder"
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If objFSO.FolderExists(strDirectory) Then
Wscript.Echo strDirectory & " already exists"
Else
'Below is the added line
Set objFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder(strDirectory)
Wscript.Echo "The folder " & strDirectory & " has just been created"
End if

Wscript.Quit
```

desktop path script

```
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strDesktop = WshShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
wscript.echo(strDesktop)
```

Con some one help me please ?

Comment: Which part specifically are you struggling with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [.BuildPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0z2z1zt%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to combine the Desktop folder path and the intended (sub)folder(name):

```
>> Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
>> Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
>> strDirectory = "Folder"
>> strDirectory = objFSO.BuildPath(WshShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop"), strDirectory)
>> WScript.Echo strDirectory
>>
C:\Documents and Settings\eh\Desktop\Folder
```

Comment: thank you Ekkehard.Horner but  if I try to run it give me "WshShell undefined" error 
I am Novice maybe my failure